# how to find a url in wordpress with php

Tags: php, wordpress

My url is `www.mysite.com/properties/property-1-someplace`

The `/property-1-someplace/` is dynamically generated.

I'm writing an if statement that asks if the url is `properties/property-1-someplace` then execute code, but `property-1-someplace` is generated by wordpress and thus is constantly changing.

How can I target pages that are in the properties directory, but access the url afterwards if I don't know what that url is?

I can use the PHP variable `$pagename` but that does not address the `properties` part of the url.

If I could do `<?php if (is_page( 'property/*.*' ) ):` that would be perfect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Sorry I misunderstood your question, here is what you are probably looking for. Note that you may have to change the regular expression pattern to `/^properties/` depending on the value of `$pagename`. If `$pagename` contains the whole URL (e.g. with domain name) then you will need to update the code with the domain name.

```
if( preg_match( '/^\/properties/', $pagename ) ) {
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will that just give me the current url though? If so that's the same as `$pagename` I need to be able to target only the urls after `/property/` if that makes sense?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure why that isn't working? Here's the code I've added: 

`<?php if( preg_match( '/^\/properties/', $pagename ) ) {
echo '<script>if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome|AppleWebKit/)) { 
    window.location.hash = "#propertycontent";
    window.location.hash = "#propertycontent";  /* these take twice */
} else {
    window.location.hash = "#propertycontent";
}</script>';
} ?>`

$pagename is just the name of the page, not the full url.

Comment: What does `$pagename` contain? You can do a `var_dump` or a `print_r` of it.

Comment: just the name of the page, so if the page is called `technoh` the $pagename will be `technol` of I want to get the whole url I can use `$the_permalink();` if that helps?

Comment: Yes, you need the complete URL without the domain name for this to work.